# Review difference between previous commit and HEAD in working copy

Tags: git

Here's the scenario I have in a code review situation.

- four commits have been made, all on master
- I want to review the differences between master and the commit prior to the fourth one
- I can do this using tools like `git diff`, but I want my working copy to appear *as if all the changes those four commits entail had not been committed yet*

The reason for this is that I want to review the changes in a broader context than the context of `git diff`, e.g. using VS Code to display changes, navigate files naturally etc.

At this stage I'm not using a branch for code reviews. Arguably I should be but that's another point.

Is it possible to:

- check out earlier commit
- update working copy to apply all commits from current commit to HEAD without updating the index
- review, then discard working copy

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` can do this quite directly:

```
git diff --cached <commit-specifier>
```

(e.g., `git diff --cached HEAD~4`) literally means:

- extract the specified commit
- diff that commit against the current proposed-next-commit

Note that `git diff --cached` means diff the proposed-next-commit against the current commit, so all this is doing is substituting in a different "starting point".  Leaving out `--cached` similarly compares the specified commit against the current working tree.

If you wish to compare a commit you've actually *made*, use `git diff commit1 commit2`, e.g., `git diff HEAD~4 HEAD`.

Use `git log` to find raw hash IDs and your mouse to cut-and-paste them.

(To diff two commits with something other than `git diff` itself, consider `git difftool --dir-diff`.)

Comment: Hello - yes, I understand that, and thank you, but is there a way to apply that diff to my working files as checked out from 4 commits earlier (repeat: just the working files, not updating the index)? I am really looking a way to make it easier to review this diff in context of the commit at that point. As I said it my question, I will ultimately most likely discard the working copy.

Comment: To diff commit X against the working tree, leave out the `--cached` option.